# How can I round negative numbers to the nearest 100?

Tags: excel, rounding

I have a formula:

```
=IF(B5>0.5,MROUND(D4*$F$2*3,100), MROUND(D4*$F$2*-1,100))
```

The problem is here:

```
MROUND(D4*$F$2*-1,100)
```

`D4*$F$2` is always positive, but `MROUND` gives me `#NUM!` because the result of `D4*$F$2*-1` is always negative.

How can I round negative numbers to the nearest 100?

Comment: does your `D4*$F$2` is always positive?

Comment: @simoco Yes that it always positive, the negative number comes from the `D4*$F$2*-1` calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes that it always positive, the negative number comes from the D4*$F$2*-1 calculation

try this one

```
=IF(B5>0.5,MROUND(D4*$F$2*3,100), -1*MROUND(D4*$F$2,100))
```

Answer (score 0):

For rounding to powers of 10 you can use ROUND function, i.e.

`=ROUND(D4*$F$2,-2)`

To add your positive/negative you can then do this to avoid repetition

`=IF(B5>0.5,1,-1)*ROUND(D4*$F$2,-2)`